# Breeze's EntityQuery.fromEntities - using custom resourceName

Tags: breeze

I'm following John Papa's course on SPA's with Durandal and Breeze and I'm having a problem with the method EntityQuery.fromEntities. Indeed, I'm watching the course mainly as a reference to understand how to use Durandal and Breeze, because I'm coding a totally different SPA.

Indeed, the one I'm coding doesn't has just one Breeze controller, it has one controller per aggregate. So for each controller I have one Breeze's EntityManager. My doubt then is the following: I have one CustomersController, and following John's course to list just the table of customer I've made a projection query and loaded just partial entities.

Now, when I'm going to access the details and editing of each customer, I need the full data. So, I've used the following code in my viewmodel:

```
function reloadCustomer(customer) {
    return EntityQuery.fromEntities(customer)
    .using(customersManager).execute()
    .then(querySucceeded);
}
```

The only problem is that this query is aimed with resourceName `Customers`. This is a problem, because since the `customersManager` has serviceName `/api/customers` the request is being made to `/api/customers/Customers` which doesn't exists.

How can I use the `EntityQuery.fromEntities` method when I have this scenario of multiple controllers, instead of a single `/api/breeze` service url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the Breeze.js docs on their site to learn more about building queries.  The method you are using assumes you have matched an entity type ('Customer') to a resource ('Customers') and that your data service is always going to hit the same controller.  You have many options on how to set it up but the easiest is to define a dataservice for your manager to define a data service your manager will use and then you can map the entity to the resource, as you see in this tutorial, or you can use  `.from()` instead of `fromEntities()`

Define a data service

```
var ds = new breeze.DataService({
    serviceName: '/api'
});
var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: ds });
```

and then you can use .from() -

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('myControllerName/customers')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @PWKad, this solves me even another problem: with this I can get rid of the multiple managers. But now I have a problem to fetch metadata. Using this approach, the manager looks for metadata at `/api/metadata` while it should look at `/api/breeze/metadata`. I didn't find on the docs how to customize where to look for metadata. How can I approach this? Thanks again for the aid.

Comment: One approach that I have seen before is to use a 'parent' manager that  contains all of the metadata and links the child managers together - I believe that the Breeze.js site has a good working example of this in the TempHire sample - http://www.breezejs.com/samples/temphire-sample